# containerApp revision update fails with code: 'EACCES'

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-container-apps

i have built a nodejs application using docker.  The image is pushed to a private ACR repository.
I want to deploy it to an Azure ContainerApp in a vnet.

In the Docker File i have opened port 80
**Contents:**

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/package*.json ./ 
RUN npm ci --omit-dev --ignore-scripts
RUN npm audit fix
COPY --from=build /app/build ./build

EXPOSE 80
USER node
ENV PORT=80
CMD ["node", "./build/index.js"]
```

The existing containerApp in Azure is deployed in a Virtual Network and has **ingress** enabled on port 80. I tested the containerApp after deploying public

```
image running on port 80: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld'
```

and page works.

I update the containerApp revision manually by editing the containerApp [image]

The containerApp pulls the image from ACR successfully, but the revision fails[image]

**In ContainerApp System logs**

```
Successfully pulled image
Created container xy-app
startup probe failed: connection refused
startup probe failed: connection refused
Persistent Failiure to start container
Container 'xy-app' was terminated with exit code '1'
```

**In ContainerApp Console logs**

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
2023-07-14T15:46:07.354907334Z     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1446:21)
2023-07-14T15:46:07.354911202Z     at listenInCluster (node:net:1511:12)
2023-07-14T15:46:07.354914899Z     Emitted 'error' event on Server instance    code: 'EACCES',
 port: 80
```

My assumption that the container cannot open port 80(which needs root access).
Even if i try giving su in Command Override input box, it fails with the same error:
[image]

**Update**

I updated the Docker file as per the answer given below:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
RUN npm audit fix
RUN npm run build


FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/package*.json ./ 
RUN npm ci --omit-dev --ignore-scripts
RUN npm audit fix
COPY --from=build /app/build ./build
RUN apk add libcap2
RUN setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(which node)
EXPOSE 80
USER node
ENV PORT=80
CMD ["node", "./build/index.js"]
```

When the docker image is getting built i am getting this error as shown:
[image]

```
/bin/sh: setcap: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(which node)' returned a non-zero code: 127
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(which node)' returned a non-zero code: 127
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 127
```

Answer (score 0):

non-root users, `USER node` can't listen to ports <1024 by default. Listen to a different port > 1024 or set something like

```
RUN apk add libcap2 && \
    setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(which node)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the DockerFile with the above code and getting the error as updated in the question above